# Click with middle button can't load onclick function on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, onclick

I'm already search a lot but still can't find the right answer.
I wonder why middle click (scroll button) can't load `onclick function` on Firefox only while on Chrome it works. So instead of `onclick function` it shows `href link` which is `javascript:void(0)`

```
<a  href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="open_tab();">
```

Javascript

```
function open_tab(){
        my_tab=window.open('http://www.google.com/', my_tab);                                   
}
```

Tell my why. Thanks a lot.

Comment: may be that event is browser specific

Comment: Try this: `<a  href="http://www.google.com/" TARGET="_blank">`. You are making use of `click` event which does not gets triggered on `mousewheel click`. As @NishadKAhamed, pointed out, it is totally bowser specific. This is the expected behaviour in chrome too but just for the sake of _better user experience_

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=180078

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this for all browsers

I made it a bit simple

```js
function open_tab(){
        my_tab=window.open('http://www.google.com/', "Google");                                   
}


var link = document.getElementById("alink");
link.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.which===1||e.which===2){
    open_tab();    
      }
});
```

```html
<a id="alink">Open Google</a>
```

The line

```
if(e.which===1||e.which===2){
```

Makes sure that the window opens only on left and middle mouse click.

It works fine for me!!!!!!!! Hope it helps!

Comment: Have you tried RUNNING code snippet i attached above?? It's functional. Please check !!!!

Comment: yes I've tried. Slow man no need caps and over mark. Got error on my firebug `InvalidAccessError: A parameter or an operation is not supported by the underlying object`

Comment: @blerrr Copy the code from my snippet and create separate web page on your desktop/local machine and then try clicking on the link. It seem  that the `stack overflow snippet is restricting` javascript from opening a pop up!

Comment: yesss it workksss.. I replace your code with mine though already checked before that nothing different between your code and mine. Thanks arjun

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a middle click on this computer to test this, but to make your middle click cross browser compliant, I would add a event listener in javascript:

```
var open = document.getElementById('opentab');

open.addEventListener ("click", function (e) {
  if (e.which === 2) {
      e.preventDefault();
      open_tab();
  }
});
```

This depends on adding an ID to your link like:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="opentab">Open Tab</a>
```

Also, correctly pointed out by espascarello, the mozilla community abandoned firing on click events on middle and right press: http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=180078